# Incorrect result implementing jump search in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement jump search in Python. The code looks logically fine to me. I am getting `-1` for all the numbers except for the first element of the array. Can someone help please?

```
def jumpsearch(array,x):
    n=len(array)
    m=int(sqrt(n))

    if array[0]>x:
        return -1

    for i in (0,n-1,m):
        if array[i]==x:
            return i
        if x<array[i]:
            for k in (i-m,i):
                if array[k]==x:
                    return k           
    return -1            

j=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(j)
jumpsearch(j,2)
```

Comment: Your for loops are iterating over specific values only… try having it iterating in a `range`… (e.g. `for i in range(0,n-1,m):`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for k in (i-m,i):` you don't iterate in a range, but `k` only takes 2 values: `i-1` and `m`.

Same for the line `for i in (0,n,m):`.

You also get uncorrect results because you never check in the last block. Indeed even by doing `for i in range(0, n, m):` you will stop when i + m >= n, so you have to check in the last part to be sure that the element is not there.

```
def jumpsearch(array, x):
    n=len(array)
    m=int(math.sqrt(n))

    if array[0] > x:
        return -1

    for i in range(0, n, m):        
        if array[i] == x:
            return i
        elif x < array[i]:
            for k in range(i-m, i):
                if array[k]==x:
                    return k 
            else:
                return -1  
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if array[j] == x:
            return j
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: Ahh thanks @newbie. Silly of me to skip such a basic check. Cheers